# How to fix TimeShift not restoring due to fstab sshfs files

Tags: ubuntu, grub, pop-os, sshfs, timeshift

I tried to update my nvidia drivers via the pop shop and it went wrong. Now I would like to restore my system with TimeShift. Pop OS does not use GRUB so when selecting restore I went to "bootloader options and deselected "(Re)Install GRUB2" and "update GRUB menu". This got rid of an error related to not being able to install GRUB2. However, I now get the following error:

I get the following error when TimeShift attempts to restore:
[image]

However if I look through dmesg I found the following errors:

```
[    6.718025] systemd-fstab-generator[401]: Checking was requested for "sshfs#nicofish@[my ssh ip address]:/media/nicofish/storageR1/", but it is not a device.
[    6.718079] systemd-fstab-generator[401]: Failed to create unit file /run/systemd/generator/mnt-desktop\x2draid\x2dstorage.mount, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?
[    6.718336] systemd-fstab-generator[401]: Checking was requested for "sshfs#nicofish@[my ssh ip address]:/media/nicofish/storageR1/", but it is not a device.
[    6.718374] systemd-fstab-generator[401]: Failed to create unit file /run/systemd/generator/mnt-2TBSamsung.mount, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab?
[    6.722298] block nvme0n1: the capability attribute has been deprecated.
[    6.726921] systemd[392]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-fstab-generator failed with exit status 1.
```

---

My inxi -b output is:

```
nicofish@pop-os:~$ inxi -b
System:
  Host: pop-os Kernel: 6.5.6-76060506-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.5 Distro: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 82JQ v: Legion 5 Pro 16ACH6H
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0T76461 WIN
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: GKCN49WW date: 11/08/2021
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 74.5 Wh (100.0%) condition: 74.5/80.0 Wh (93.2%)
CPU:
  Info: 8-core AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics [MT MCP] speed (MHz):
    avg: 2223 min/max: 400/4463
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q] driver: N/A
  Device-2: AMD Cezanne driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Device-3: Acer Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 2560x1600~165Hz
  OpenGL:
    renderer: RENOIR (renoir LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.54 6.5.6-76060506-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1pop0~1699535617~22.04~6cd9a72
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    driver: r8169
  Device-2: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: iwlwifi
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.16 TiB used: 770.78 GiB (64.6%)
Info:
  Processes: 421 Uptime: 31m Memory: 58.7 GiB used: 8.6 GiB (14.6%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.13
```

I have a TimeShift snapshot from over a year ago that I could restore to, but I would like to avoid going that far back.

Does anyone one know how I could fix this and restore my Pop OS system to my last snapshot?

Edit: I tried downgrading my rsync to version 3.2.3-8ubuntu3 and I got the same error but now the sender=3.2.3 and generator=3.2.3 as opposed to 3.2.7